# Empty preview map Tilestache Mbtiles

Tags: tiles, mapnik, tilemill, tilestache

So, I generated a map on tilemill and exported the mbtiles file. I've setup Tilestache, and all required dependencies. I tried the OSM preview provided by default which worked fine.

When I tried to load a MBtiles file through the Tilestache config file(.cfg), the terminal doesn't show me any errors (infact it shows me all the HTTP calls perfectly fine), but the preview output at 127.0.0.1:portno/{layername}/preview.html seems to be a blank map!

When I did explicit HTTP calls to specific png images, the images are empty. In other words, I see empty outputs from it. I also tried different MBtiles files and I'm still facing the same output.

What could be the problem here??

My Tilestache config file:

```
{
  "cache":
  {
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "layers": 
  {
    "roads":
    {
        "provider": {"name": "mbtiles", "tileset": "ward.mbtiles"},
        "preview": {"zoom": 15, "ext": "png"} 

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default OSM preview page's URL is  ip_address:port_number/osm/preview.html#10/37.8000/-122.2600 which indicate the zoom level is 10, so I guess you did not export mbtiles file up to that zoom level that's why TileStache generates empty page then you could manually change the zoom level and lat/lon value to force TileStache to work out preview page.

I have tested method above which shows the truth and I hope it will help you out.